# Iterate over all resources of a given type dynamically in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to make the following more dynamic but can't figure out how to reference all instances of aws_subnet. I tried a wilcard (eg., `for subnet in aws_subnet.*`) but it complains that it wants a specific instance referenced.

```
subnets_by_role = merge(
  { for subnet in aws_subnet.public :
    subnet.tags.subnet_role => subnet...
  },
  {
  for subnet in aws_subnet.private :
    subnet.tags.subnet_role => subnet...
})
```

Comment: Without the code you have for subnets it is really hard to tell.

Comment: Terraform doesn't currently support referencing all resources of a specific type via wildcard (or any other method). It's been a feature request on the Terraform GitHub project for a few years now. The way you are currently doing it is probably as good as you can get it with the current version of Terraform.

Answer (score 1):

The name `aws_subnet` alone does not exist in Terraform. The most granular addressable object is a whole resource, like `aws_subnet.public`. This is because Terraform uses these references to infer a dependency graph of operations and so it needs to see exactly which resources refer to each other.

What you wrote in your question is the smallest possible way to write this in Terraform, because it explicitly tells Terraform that this `subnets_by_role` value depends on both `aws_subnet.public` and `aws_subnet.private`, and so Terraform can infer that anything that refers to this value indirectly depends on both of those resources.

If you need this united collection of all of your subnets in multiple places in your module then one option would be to gather them all into a single collection and then refer to that collection elsewhere:

```
locals {
  all_subnets = tomap(merge(
    { for k, v in aws_subnet.public : "public:${k}" => v },
    { for k, v in aws_subnet.private : "private:${k}" => v },
  ))

  subnets_by_role = tomap({
    for subnet in local.all_subnets :
    subnet.tags.subnet_role => subnet
  })
}
```

But of course that refactoring is only really productive if you'll be using `local.all_subnets` in multiple other locations in your module.